# I am finding difficulties to solve an expression

Tags: c, variables, ascii

I am finding difficulties to solve an expression please help me to do so.

Declare four variables of type char. Initialize one variable to ‘z’. Initialize the other variables to the ASCII integer value for ‘z’, the ASCII octal value for ‘z’, and 
the ASCII hexadecimal value for ‘z’.

Comment: please post what you need and what you tryed ..

Comment: I want to solve this question. @Sarath

Comment: what output you need mr.bilal

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a `char` variable and assign the value. To assign hex prefix with `0x`, for octal use `0` and for decimal just write the number with no prefix.

The decimal ascii value of `'z'` is 122.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a = 122;
  char b = 0x7a;
  char c = 0172;
  char d = 'z';

  putchar(a);
  putchar(b);
  putchar(c);
  putchar(d);
}
```

All these `char` variables have the same value so four `z`s will be printed.